# Отображение информации из массива в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Не могу разобраться как выводить данные из трёхмерного массива в DataGrid. Получаю данные из БД в массив вида:

```
[0]{id, int, string1, {int1, int2, int3,...}}
[1]{id, int, string1, {int1, int2, int3,...}}
...
```

Нужно вывести всё это в таблицу вида

```
| string1 | int1 | int2 | int3 | ... |
| string1 | int1 | int2 | int3 | ... |
```

Пробовал использовать

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = Array;
```

Неполучается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Преобразовал входной массив до одноразмерного. Теперь это массив вида

```
[0]{id, int, string1, int1, int2, int3,...}
[1]{id, int, string1, int1, int2, int3,...}
...
```

Вывожу этот массив в DataGrid
**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid_choise_feed" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
          Loaded="grid_choise_feed_Loaded" FrozenColumnCount="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" AlternationCount="2"   >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding [2]}" MaxWidth="200" Width="200" MinWidth="70"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="20" CanUserResize="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding [4]}" MaxWidth="70" Width="50" CanUserResize="False"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Остальные колонки в которые должны выводится параметры int1, int2, int3,....  генерирую программно:
**C#**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col.Header = Parameters[i];
        col.Width = 60;
        col.ElementStyle = style;

        grid_choise_feed.Columns.Add(col);
    }
```

Не получается указать свойство binding для вновь создаваемых столбцов.
Пробовал писать: `col.binding = new (Binding ("[5]")`. Ничего не отображает.

Comment: Создайте шаблон для столбца SyncRoot, который будет ваш массив Int32 переводить в строковое значение, удобное для пользователя.

Comment: Как в ответе сделать не получилось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему написав

```
col.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("["+i.ToString()+"]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, как подсказывают в комментариях, можно переопределить шаблон для столбцов.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Array}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LongLength" Binding="{Binding LongLength}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank" Binding="{Binding Rank}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SyncRoot">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SyncRoot}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                 </ItemsControl>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <!-- Остальные колонки по-такому же принципу -->
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```